# Prevent form submit by hitting Enter in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to prevent the form submission by hitting the Enter key.

Here is the code i tried:

```js
snippet_animation.registry.form_builder_send.include({
 start: function(editable_mode){
 var self = this;
 this.$target.find('.o_website_form_send').on('click',function(e) {
 console.log('e.keyCOde',e.keyCode); // Here prints undefined
if ( e.keyCode === 13){
  e.preventDefault();
}else{

  self.send(e);
}
});

this._super(editable_mode);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution,

```js
$("input").keydown(function(event){
if(event.keyCode === 13){
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
});
```

If anybody have any better solution than this please post.

Answer (score 0):

Te best solution is to prevent the keydown event, as you did it's the best way.